# Job not getting paused in clustered environment

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler in my web application which is running in a clusterd environment. When i am pausing a particular job from code only one managed node gets affected and the other one continues to run that job (as logs are generated on only this node after the job has been paused). I want that when i pause the job, it should affect both the nodes. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you haven't provided more info, here are some rules from Quartz docs regarding clustering: Never run clustering on separate machines, unless their clocks are synchronized using some form of time-sync service (daemon) that runs very regularly (the clocks must be within a second of each other). See http://www.boulder.nist.gov/timefreq/service/its.htm if you are unfamiliar with how to do this.
Never start (scheduler.start()) a non-clustered instance against the same set of database tables that any other instance is running (start()ed) against. Hope it helps.